# Dealing with null method argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have tried implementing my custom map function and i get this error which does not tell me much.

```
mymap::(a->b)->[a]->[b]
mymap _ [] =[]
mymap null (x:xs)=x:xs
mymap f (x:xs)=f x : mymap f xs
```

Error message:

```
* Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          mymap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Why is it not correct since i provide a predicate from `a` to `b`, a source list of `a` and i expect a list of `b`'s

Comment: mymap null (x:xs)=x:xs.....does this line mean "if I put null function to mymap, it should return the same list."? then you will get a [a]. I guess it's the reason. Which line does the error point out?

Comment: Yes this is how i thought it should deal with an empty predicate.

Comment: Apparently the third line is underlined in the error.More specifically the expression.

Comment: The problem was indeed the 3-rd line returning the initial list.How should i deal with the return type signature if i want to return the initial list  if empty predicate...?Is there something like a conditional return type ?  [a] | [b]?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't won't use the initial list directly, instead giving null function to indicate you want a origninal one?

Comment: mymap::(a->a)->[a]->[a]    it allows you to use a id function to return the initial list. But in that way, all your funtion for map has type (a->a). Is that what you want?

Comment: I just wanted to exclude all null posibilities.I thought that when i write a function i have to cover all edge cases so in my case null source list and null predicate.

Comment: One point I just saw: I think your null in `mymap null (x:xs)=x:xs` means "every function you put into map because it's just a pattern match word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168620/discussion-between-johnny-liao-and-bercovici-adrian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no `null` pointer in Haskell**, so this line:

```
mymap null (x:xs) = (x:xs)
```

is equivalent to

```
mymap _ s = s
```

Since `null` simply matches everything regardless of value, being a valid identifier. You could say, for instance, `null = 6`, and it would be valid in Haskell.

Thus giving the function type `mymap :: b -> [a] -> [a]`, which is different from the type you intended.

You should remove that line. The 'correct' implementation is:

```
mymap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mymap _ []     = []
mymap f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

You're right to pattern match on both `[]` and `(:)`, because in  the declaration of the list type, both occur:

```
-- Compiler magic occurs here! This is not usually valid syntax
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

We therefore see that in a list there are only two possibilities, both of which we must match. However, this is not the case with functions.

Comment: And how would i deal with an empty predicate?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian no such thing exists. If you mean `id`, then that matches it in any case.

Comment: `null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool`. Why do you say there is no `null` in Haskell ? It tests whether a list is empty for example.

Comment: So there's no equivalent to a NULL function pointer argument in haskell? e.g:  void myfunction( void (*arg)() ) and i don't have to treat this case?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent That is a definition in Data.Foldable. I mean a builtin.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Pointers don't exist in vanilla Haskell. You don't have to treat this case.